# Stop a fadeOut within a callback of another fadeOut

Tags: jquery

I am trying to stop an animation from propagating on a call back of another animation, i have tried to stop the animation directly by adding `.stop(true, true)` onto the element that i wish to stop from fading but it doesn't seem to stop the animation.

I have created a fiddle -> follow the link http://jsfiddle.net/5rEWa/

Here is the code:

```
$('.fadeMe').delay(3000).fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $('.meToo').fadeOut(1000);
    });


    $('#stop').click(function(){
       $('.meToo').stop(true, true);
    });
```

*As always stack i am greatful for your help*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/5rEWa/8/

solution is to call `stop().animate({opacity:'100'});` to stop the fadeOut() animation **after** it has started. If you also want to be able to cancel it before it has started, you'd need to do something like this:

```
$(function(){
    var isCancelled = false;
    $('.fadeMe').delay(3000).fadeOut(1000, function(){
        if (!isCancelled )
            $('.meToo').fadeOut(1000);
    });

    $('#stop').click(function(){
       isCancelled = true;
       $('.meToo').stop().animate({opacity:'100'});
    });       
});
```

Comment: That didn't work bud, i am trying to stop the animation even if it has started to run, your solution in Chrome did nothing, unless i am missing something ?

Comment: check my jsfiddle - it stops the green box fading out and resets it to initial state: http://jsfiddle.net/3MBrB/ Isn't that what you need? (I am also using Chrome) it only works after the green box starts its animation, of course.

Comment: it doesn't do that via your link

Comment: ok i understand that now, what if the greenbox has not even started it's animation how would i disable it from propagating?

Comment: see my edit. pretty straight forward when you think about it :)